# Can't get an item's attributes from a DynamoDB table

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, null, amazon-dynamodb

I have an iOS app written in Swift. In this app I'm trying to load an item from a DynamoDB table, but for some reason, I couldn't load any item, even though all the details were correct.

I have installed the AWS SDK using CocoaPods, after I followed all the instructions in order to correctly install it. I have installed the following libraries: `AWSCognito`, `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider`, `AWSDynamoDB`, `AWSS3`, `AWSSNS`.

After that, I have added my AWS credentials in the `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>AWS</key>
<dict>
    <key>DynamoDBObjectMapper</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Default</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Region</key>
            <string>USEast1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>DynamoDB</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Default</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Region</key>
            <string>USEast1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CredentialsProvider</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CognitoIdentity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Region</key>
                <string>USEast1</string>
                <key>PoolId</key>
                <string>myPoolId</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I've created a mapper file called `Contact.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import AWSDynamoDB

class Contact: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {

    var id: String?
    var name: String?

    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
        return "Contacts"
    }

    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Then, I've added the following code in `ViewController.swift` file, inside the `viewDidLoad` method. The code should get an item from a table, save its attributes, and set its name attribute to be the title of the screen:

```
import UIKit
import AWSDynamoDB

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: Properties
    struct GlobalVars {
        static let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        static let id: String = "id"

        static var name: String?
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        GlobalVars.dynamoDBObjectMapper.load(Contact.self, hashKey: GlobalVars.id, rangeKey: nil).continueWith(block: {(task: AWSTask<AnyObject>!) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
            } else if let taskResult = task.result as? Contact {
                // Save the information
                GlobalVars.name = taskResult.name

                // Set title to the name
                self.navigationItem.title = GlobalVars.name!
            }
            return nil
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

The problem is that the app crashes when I'm trying to assign the `GlobalVars.name` variable to the navigation bar title. It crashes with the following message: `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

I've tried to print `taskResult.name` instead, but it just printed `nil`.

But it didn't print anything to the console. I've added the following code to the `Info.plist` file, but that didn't work also:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>amazonaws.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
      </dict>
      <key>amazonaws.com.cn</key>
      <dict>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
      </dict>
  </dict>
```

When I'm checking in the variables area at the bottom of the editor, I can see that all of the item's attributes are `nil`.

After a deep search, I've noticed something very weird. When I changed the name of the table to a table which doesn't exist, I have received the following message in the console:

```
The request failed. Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSDynamoDBErrorDomain Code=7 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ResourceNotFoundException, message=Requested resource not found}
```

When I'm running it with a correct table name, but with a wrong hash key which refers to an item which doesn't exist in the table, I don't get anything. It doesn't crashes or prints a message to the console. It just keeps running like I'm don't asking for anything from the DynamoDB table.

What can I do about it? I've already searched all over the internet but I couldn't find anything about it yet... Could you please help me solving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, due to a change in Swift 4 behavior change of inferencing @objc, I was supposed to add `@objcMembers` before the class declaration in the `Contact.swift` file